# Implementing Slow-motion with LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am having trouble implementing smooth slow-motion rendering in LibGDX with the Artemis framework. I understand how to change "delta" in order for this to work (using [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/slow-motion-libgdx/30515/msg/281841/view.html)), but I'm unable to figure out how to actually implement it in the `Screen` interface's render method. How can I change the delta parameter of the `Screen`'s render method to essentially slow down time?

My Screen Class:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private SpriteRenderSystem spriteRenderSystem;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Game game;
    private World world;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public GameScreen(Game game){
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 640, 480);
        this.game = game;

        world = new World();
        world.setManager(new GroupManager());

        spriteRenderSystem = world.setSystem(new SpriteRenderSystem(camera), true);
        world.setSystem(new VelocitySystem());
        world.setSystem(new AccelerationSystem());
        world.setSystem(new CollisionSystem());
        world.setSystem(new ExpirationSystem());

        world.initialize();

        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i += 4){
            EntityFactory.createBlock(world, i*16, 0, "tiles/water").addToWorld();
            EntityFactory.createBlock(world, (i+1) * 16, 0, "tiles/grass").addToWorld();
            EntityFactory.createBlock(world, (i+2) * 16, 0, "tiles/mud").addToWorld();
            EntityFactory.createBlock(world, (i+3) * 16, 0, "tiles/sand").addToWorld();
        }

        for(Entity e : EntityFactory.createExplosion(world, 320, 240)){
            e.addToWorld();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // NEED HELP HERE
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        world.setDelta(delta);
        world.process();
        spriteRenderSystem.process();
    }

    (...)
}
```

Note:  I am using the LibGDX + Artemis demo [SpriteRenderSystem](https://code.google.com/p/spaceship-warrior/source/browse/src/com/gamadu/spaceshipwarrior/systems/SpriteRenderSystem.java) for rendering entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a float:

```
public float speed = 0.5F; //half for example
```

And in your render method, just multiply your delta with it:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    delta*=speed;  //<---

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    world.setDelta(delta);
    world.process();
    spriteRenderSystem.process();
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this.  It doesn't seem to render any differently though.  Is it because GDX renders using the unchanged delta before it reads the overridden render method?

Comment: It should work. Libgdx doesn't render anything itself. It calls the overridden render method and that's what is being executed. If you update your gamelogic only by 0.5 delta in every step, it has to result in a slowdown.